# Can I access the XBox Live service in Slovakia?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm about to buy a xbox 360. What must I buy or how much do I have to pay to play online?

I thought I'd get to play if I just bought a game with online content, but the console requires an "xbox live" subscription. How much does it cost and how much does it last?

Comment: where do you live?

Comment: slovakia slovak republic

Comment: Isn't this a shopping recommendation. See the [faq](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @Ronan No, it isn't.

Comment: @badp Ok, as long as it is asking for official purchase and not just the best deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xbox Live service is now (11/13/13) [available in Slovakia](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/Countries). :)

Comment: so that mean if i buy xbox and a game for example the new fight night i could not play it online?

Comment: @Csabi Yes, and "only" because you happen to live in the wrong country. Weren't you warned when you bought the console?

Comment: :( i do not buy it yet, i think i will buy ps3...i m disapointed

Comment: @Csabi The [Playstation Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Store) is also unavailable in Slovakia, although the [Playstation Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Network) is (just so you know).

Answer (score 0):

in the UK the prices are

Gold - 12 Month £39.99

Gold - 1 Month £5.99

Gold Family Pack (4) - 12 Month - £69.99

EDIT* I just noticed that your asking about xbox live in Slovakia.

apparently what you can do is get someone to create an xbox gamertag for you in a supported country and then recover it in slovakia you can then add prepaid cards to it which you can use one of the online services to purchase prepaid xbox codes (i.e http://live-codes.com).  This is just after doing some research so if anyone else can confirm or deny this?

Comment: Hi @CaspErTbH, welcome to Gaming -- since you realized you weren't answering the question exactly, may I suggest you delete it or edit it to an appropriate answer?